# Generalized linear (mixed) model, binomial - help!

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, glmm, overdispersion

I work in biology and I´ve done an experiment exposing an invertebrate to a pesticide at different temperatures. One of my endpoints is hatching success of their eggs. The animals lay clutches of eggs, usually 10-30 eggs. My impression is that I shouldn’t model the data using proportions as datapoints (e.g., 0.7 proportion of the eggs in one clutch hatched), but rather use raw data (1/0 for hatched/not hatched, per egg). Then I need to add “clutch-ID” as a random factor. I, therefore, plan to use a generalized linear mixed model (`glmer()` from the **lme4** package) with binomial family `link = "logit"`.

My model:

```r
glmer(hatchingsuccess ~ Temperature + Pesticide + (1 | clutch.id), 
      data = eggdata, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

The sample size is approx. 8000 eggs (in about 500 clutches). I also first included an interaction term with `Temperature * Pesticide`, but then nothing was significant, so I eliminated that.

Summary:

```r
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial ( logit )
Formula: hatchingsuccess ~ Temperature + Pesticide + (1 | clutch.id)
   Data: eggdata

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  6879.3   6914.3  -3434.6   6869.3     8139 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-5.2772 -0.2007  0.2111  0.4408  3.7051 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Batch.id (Intercept) 5.121    2.263   
Number of obs: 8144, groups:  Batch.id, 560

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)       0.62213    0.43920   1.416  0.15663   
Temperature       0.08385    0.02709   3.096  0.00196 **
lowPesticide -0.29740    0.25770  -1.154  0.24847   
highPesticide -0.50853    0.26549  -1.915  0.05543 . 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
optimizer (Nelder_Mead) convergence code: 0 (OK)
Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 0.0023972 (tol = 0.002, component 1)
```

The proportions of eggs hatched look like this (the different colours represent pesticide treatments, and the three plots are for three different temperatures.

[image]

These are diagnostic plots using the package DHARMa:

[image]

1. Does this R output from the model and diagnostics look ok? I got an answer about the converge problem and will look into that.
2. Is it ok to present these proportion plots and refer to model statistics, or do I need to plot single datapoints on the y-axis and a line for the model? I think these proportion plots more clearly show the data/results, but I need to have some stats to refer to.

Comment: Greetings and welcome to CV! I would edit your question to whatever is your "big problem". Questions get closed here if they get jam-packed full of things for people to answer. You increase the likelihood of getting an answer when your question is straightforward to provide a solution to.

Comment: Btw your DHARMA plots look more than reasonable. One of your categories looks wonky but that's not really the end of the world in my opinion. It would be different if it had several problematic boxplots.

Comment: I'm a bit worried about the failure to converge in fitting the model, although it came close. You might try altering the control settings for `glmer`. Also, you can fit a binomial model in a situation like this, without having to use a random effect, by specifying the outcome for each clutch as "a two-column integer matrix: the first column gives the number of successes and the second the number of failures" (Help page for `family` in R). Maybe try that.

Comment: Good catch. I somehow missed that.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @ShawnHemelstrand, that makes sense, Ive removed some questions/text. :)

Comment: Thank you @EdM, I will try the two-column approach now using glm. I dont really understand what the convergence issue is, but I guess its best not to get any warnings. thanks!

Comment: Always pay attention to warnings. In this case, the default setting was to consider the fit complete when the magnitude of a gradient was less than 0.002; yours came close, at 0.0024, so it might not be a big deal. You can specify different optimizers, numbers of iterations, etc. to `glmer()` to deal with difficult fits. You should learn about that if you are going to do a lot of mixed-modeling. I suspect that the 2-column approach will avoid the problem completely in this case.

Comment: _Is it ok to present these proportion-plots and refer to model statistics, or do I need to plot single datapoints on the y axis and a line for the model?_ What specifically do you mean here? Are you asking if you should produce a scatterplot with the fitted regression line on it? I would say more information is always better than less information in the stats world.

Comment: Thanks, @EdM. Can I write in my manuscript that Ive weighted for the different batches when I go for the 2-column approach? Or is that not correct?

Comment: Yes, @ShawnHemelstrand, thats what I was asking, thanks, I will make the scatterplot then.

Comment: The 2-column approach should give you the same values as another option for binomial regression, defining the outcome "as a numerical vector with values between 0 and 1, interpreted as the proportion of successful cases (with the total number of cases given by the weights)." So it's OK to say that each clutch was weighted by the total number of eggs.

Comment: Thank you so much, @EdM!